# Implementing both controltemplate and datatriggers for a textbox control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried implementing controltemplate and datatriggers both for textbox.. the Xaml code is as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Uid="txtagevals" x:Name="txtAge" Height="25" Width="80" Background="Wheat"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                                        <TextBox.Template>
                                                            <ControlTemplate x:Uid ="txtagevals" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5">
                                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                                                                </Border>
                                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Age}" Value="18">
                                                                        <Setter **TargetName=""** Property="Text" Value="Green" />
                                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </TextBox.Template>
                                                    </TextBox>
```

could you please help me... with..what should be my **Target Name=""** in the above code..Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave out the target name, that should work.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more examples.